# Read line containing variables from file

Tags: python

I need to read the row like:

```
"hello %" % name
```

from a file and then use it in the code. For e.g.:

```
name = "Joe"
row = open("hello.txt", "r").readline().strip()
print row
```

And desired result of run of this program should be :

```
hello Joe
```

and not

```
hello %" % name
```

Are there any means to accomplish it?

Comment: Why are you using that as your template format? Consider using something compatible with https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the sub-string with the variable.

```
name = "Joe"
row = open("hello.txt", "r").readline().strip()
row = row.replace('%" % name', name)
print row
```

Output:

```
hello Joe
```

Comment: Actually it will work for my current needs. Thank you! BTW out of curiosity is there way to damp the variable name into json format and then load it as variable name, not the string with variable name in it?

Comment: Well JSON format would be `{"name": "Joe"}`, referencing it would be as simple as `json.name`. If the answer helped you please mark it as correct so others in the future can be helped also. :)